# Type inference with generic array in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

```js
// Generic Constraints
class Car {
  print() {
    console.log('I am a car')
  }
}
class House {
  print() {
    console.log('I am a house')
  }
}

interface Printable {
  print(): void;
}

// tell Typescript that I promise the T type will satisfy the Printable interface
function printHousesOrCars<T extends Printable>(...arr: T[]): void {
  arr.forEach(item => item.print())
}

printHousesOrCars(1, 2, 3) // This line went wrong,I can understand
printHousesOrCars(new House(), new Car()) // this line Typescript infer T[] is Car[], I cannot understand, why shouldn't it be (House|Car)[]
```

I cannot understand the last line, and if I wrote

> const x = [new House(), new Car()] // Typescript will infer x as (House|Car)[]

Comment: Your `House` and `Car` have the same [structure](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), so the compiler sees them as the same type.  You should [distinguish them at the type level](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible), say by adding incompatible properties, like a `manufacturer` property to `Car` and a `numBathrooms` property to `House`.

Comment: What if you change your function to: `function printHousesOrCars<T extends Printable[]>(...arr: T): void { //etc...` ?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks,this really helps. Does it mean using genrics, TS won't infer the type as a union type, it must be a specific type.

Comment: @flavio won't work bro,then T[] is a 2D array

Comment: @crazyones110 it'll not be restricted to a 2D array. The length of the array really depends on how you call the function. If you call it with 10 parameters, it'll infer to a tuple with 10 itens. [Look this playground code](https://shorturl.at/lmnsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line will be interpreted by the Typescript as a two elements tuple of type [House, Car].

`const x = [new House(), new Car()] // Typescript will infer x as (House|Car)[]`

It's a bit confusing, I know, because of both using the same syntax i.e the `[` and `]`.

Now you can modify the function signature a bit in order to produce, what I believe, more correct typing.

```
function printHousesOrCars<T extends Printable[]>(...arr: T): void {
  arr.forEach(item => item.print())
}
```

On the call site the above will be resolved as a function with first arg `House` and a second `Car`.

```
printHousesOrCars(new House(), new Car()) // [House, Car]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEHEFMDtIJwJYGNQGED20DOAXOBDBaHLAKCQBt8ss185QBvU0UAB0WIAoBKJl1qCSYs6CpAB0FdAHMuAcgCSofAFsVQ+vJ4CAvqX2VqtABLoArlkj9WHIjl43Bw7GMnS5SlevygAFhZW2noGpKT28ABm+EjWAAqcOPgARuJOdtw8AFygAG7oCAAmANyhpCCgOJAUFKAAKgCebJBYSIhsOJV++J3KHOiqCFZd1nWVTdYA7gg1oFg9Q5ENI6AJ9ilpEXDRsaSR5tBIOAiY7Ilmli0A8nCo9FgAPGOQAB5V0IW0a8QbkADaAF0AHxcCRg+hwHJ1bJ5AqFJwQiSRdBwACiMT8XAQVXUAF4gaBsZBVBIMg4eDp9KQyRcrFgbnc4FguABGAA0oAATByAMx8Cp1PxDUAUIhTGCdSZwTAyNnKJD4aCgA6FeC4RWFannQLXW73LiwSagWmQXgcw10OC8flgP4mjmMgFAA)
[More on the rest parameters subject](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters)

I hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: you mean all union type array will be interpreted as tuple? like `const y = [1, true, 'hello'] `. Actually it's [number, boolean, string] tuple instead of (number|boolean|string)[] when cursor hovering. Typescript treat `(number|boolean|string)[]` as a notation for tuple for simplicity?